# IIS 6.0 file upload

Tags: iis-6, filesystems, asp

I am using IIS 6.0. I want to setup a folder where user can upload some files. Can anyone suggest a step by step procedure for that?

Comment: FTP <-- Use it.

Comment: I was stuck with the file permission.Now it is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either write an HTML/ASPX/Javascript/PHP/whatever page that has a file-picker and transmits the selected file from the client to the server via HTTP or HTTPS. You'll have to code this yourself or get a template from somewhere.

or

You can enable FTP and have people FTP files to the server. FTP is bad for many reasons, the biggest one is that it passes credentials in plain-text. Unfortunately, with IIS 6.0 as your web platform, you don't have the option to use FTPS.